# WCF ServiceHost throws exception when UI client exits

Tags: c#, wcf, service, .net-4.0

I am creating a a service which I am hosting in a Console Application. It contains a single method to get data from the service, and a couple of methods that can be executed on the server.

In order to test the service I made a simple WinForms application that connects to the service and calls the operations on the host. This seemingly works just fine, but when I added service tracing to the config file to see what was going on I noticed that an exception is thrown on the service side as soon as I close the UI client:

```
<TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error">
<TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/nb-NO/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier>
<Description>Throwing an exception.</Description>
<AppDomain>WCF.Host.vshost.exe</AppDomain>
    <Exception>
        <ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType>
        <Message>
            An existing connection was forcibly closedby the remote host
        </Message>
        <StackTrace>   
            at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.FinishOperationAsyncFailure(SocketError socketError, Int32 bytesTransferred, SocketFlags flags)   at System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncEventArgs.CompletionPortCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
        </StackTrace>
        <ExceptionString>
            System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        </ExceptionString>
        <NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode>
    </Exception>
</TraceRecord>
```

(I've added a ConsoleTraceListener to the config so that I can see the warnings as soon as they occur.)

When this happens it doesn't affect the server side as far as I can tell, no exceptions are thrown in the console application that hosts the service, and if I restart the UI client it happily lets me perform the operations against the host.

Even so, this is an exception I'd very much like to catch at the host side so that I could handle it. In my opinion, any sign of an exception in the trace log should be investigated, but I simply can't understand where I can catch this error in my code. The Closed and Faulted events on the channel doesn't seem to fire at all.

I've recreated the problem in this VS 2012 solution that can be downloaded here:
http://db.tt/7l2Dnkpr (110 kB)

It consists of three projects, a DLL with the service definitions, a console host and a WinForms UI client. This replicates the setup I have in the real application, but this test is a lot simpler. The solution is setup to start multiple projects, so it should be straight forward to test it.

The WCF.Host application creates a host that is listening on **net.tcp://localhost:5000/singleservice**
In the UI client, click "*GetObjects*". This creates the channel to the servicehost and calls the *GetObjects()* method on it. 
Now, exit the UI application and notice the trace output in the console window.

Can anyone see a reason why this would happen, and/or how I could handle the exception in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're holding a reference to service object in your wcf client application (WCF.ClientUI). So you've to close the channel before exiting client process. Add the following code in client, you'll not get any exceptions on closing the client application.

```
    protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnClosing(e);
        ((IChannel)service).Close();
    }
```